# Grouping bar and line charts

Tags: javascript, d3.js, charts

I am trying to group bar chart and line chart in d3 js and I followed one  [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33541939/line-and-bar-chart-combo-in-nvd3) for that purpose,

Here is what my Ajax is returning in response:

```
[
    {
        "date_created": "2017-12-27", 
        "jobs_fail": 19, 
        "jobs_resub": 31, 
        "jobs_success": 50
    }, 
    {
        "date_created": "2017-12-29", 
        "jobs_fail": 18, 
        "jobs_resub": 25, 
        "jobs_success": 44
    }, 
    {
        "date_created": "2017-12-28", 
        "jobs_fail": 8, 
        "jobs_resub": 24, 
        "jobs_success": 44
    }, 
    {
        "date_created": "2018-01-02", 
        "jobs_fail": 2, 
        "jobs_resub": 0, 
        "jobs_success": 0
    }
```

]

And what I am trying to show is displaying the `jobs_fail` and `jobs_resub` as a bar and `jobs_sucess` as line chart in same graphs with respect to `date_created`,

Here is my code for that purpose.

```
<script>
function get_data() {
    console.log("create post is working!") // sanity check
    return $.ajax({
        url : "/group/guest/query/", // the endpoint
        type : "GET", // http method
    });
};


var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();



var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);
var colorRange = d3.scale.category20();
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
    .range(colorRange.range());
var divTooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(10, "");

var svg = d3.select("#chart").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var ajdata = get_data();
var k = [];
ajdata.success(function (data) {

var obj  = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
alert(data);
var options = d3.keys(obj[0]).filter(function(key) { if (key != "date_created" & key != "jobs_success" ) { return key }}); // & key != "date_created"){return key} });

var line_option = d3.keys(obj[0]).filter(function(key) { if (key == "jobs_success" & key == "date_created"){return key} });
alert(options);


obj.forEach(function(d) {
    d.valores = options.map(function(name) {return { name: name, value: +d[name]}; });});


x0.domain(obj.map(function(d) { return d.date_created; }));
x1.domain(options).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(obj, function(d) { return d3.max(d.valores, function(d) { return d.value; }); })]);



var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x1(d.date_created); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.jobs_success); });

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "x axis")
    .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
    .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "y axis")
    .call(yAxis)
    .append("text")
    .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
    .attr("y", 6)
    .attr("dy", ".71em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text("Number of jobs");

var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
    .data(obj)
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "rect")
    .attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + x0(d.date_created) + ",0)"; });

bar.selectAll("rect")
    .data(function(d) { return d.valores; })
    .enter().append("rect")
    .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
    .attr("x", function(d) { return x1(d.name); })
    .attr("y", function(d) { return y(d.value); })
    .attr("value", function(d){return d.name;})
    .attr("height", function(d) { return height - y(d.value); })
    .style("fill", function(d) { return color(d.name); });

bar
    .on("mousemove", function(d){
        divTooltip.style("left", d3.event.pageX+10+"px");
        divTooltip.style("top", d3.event.pageY-25+"px");
        divTooltip.style("display", "inline-block");
        var x = d3.event.pageX, y = d3.event.pageY
        var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
        l = elements.length
        l = l-1
        elementData = elements[l].__data__
        divTooltip.html((d.date_created)+"<br>"+elementData.name+"<br>"+elementData.value);
    });
bar
    .on("mouseout", function(d){
        divTooltip.style("display", "none");
    });


var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
    .data(options.slice())
    .enter().append("g")
    .attr("class", "legend")
    .attr("transform", function(d, i) { return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")"; });

legend.append("rect")
    .attr("x", width - 18)
    .attr("width", 18)
    .attr("height", 18)
    .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
    .attr("x", width - 24)
    .attr("y", 9)
    .attr("dy", ".35em")
    .style("text-anchor", "end")
    .text(function(d) { return d; });
svg.append("path")
     //.data(obj)
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line(obj));
```

**UPDATE**

[image: Output]

What problem I am facing is I am able to render bar but not the line chart on bars.

I am trying to debug but not able to do so.

Please let me know what might I am doing wrong here.

Comment: Can you provide an example of this code, as it currently works, on Codepen?

Comment: @ChrisApplegate I am getting the son for Ajax request so not sure how to do however I have already given the Ajax response and complete code.I  modified the son response  please check

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have some minor problems and a big problem.

The minor problems are:

1. Your `y` scale should take into account the maximum value in your dataset:

   ```
   y.domain([0, d3.max(obj, function(d) {
       return d.jobs_success
   })]);
   ```
2. Your line generator should use `x0`. Besides that, you'll have to move the line by half rangeBand:

   ```
   .x(function(d) {
       return x0(d.date_created) + x0.rangeBand() / 2;
   })
   ```
3. By default, a `<path>` has a black fill. Change it:

   ```
   .style("fill", "none")
   ```

Those, however, are minor problems. The biggest problem lies here, in the `data()` method:

```
svg.append("path")
    .data(obj)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Let's see in detail what's happening here. You're passing the `obj` array to the `data()`. However, if you do this, each **element** of that array will be passed, individually, to the line generator.

So, supposing that this is your array...

```
["foo", "bar", "baz"]
```

...what you're passing to the line generator is just:

```
"foo".
```

You have some different solutions here. First, you can pass the array to the line generator directly, as you did in your edit. Second, you can wrap the array in an outer array:

```
svg.append("path")
    .data([obj])
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

That way, the whole `obj` array will be passed to the line generator.

Or, third, you can use `datum`:

```
svg.append("path")
    .datum(obj)
    .attr("class", "line")
    .attr("d", line);
```

Here is your code with those changes and using `datum` to draw the path:

```js
var obj = [{
  "date_created": "2017-12-27",
  "jobs_fail": 19,
  "jobs_resub": 31,
  "jobs_success": 50
}, {
  "date_created": "2017-12-29",
  "jobs_fail": 18,
  "jobs_resub": 25,
  "jobs_success": 44
}, {
  "date_created": "2017-12-28",
  "jobs_fail": 8,
  "jobs_resub": 24,
  "jobs_success": 44
}, {
  "date_created": "2018-01-02",
  "jobs_fail": 2,
  "jobs_resub": 0,
  "jobs_success": 0
}];

var margin = {
    top: 20,
    right: 20,
    bottom: 30,
    left: 40
  },
  width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right,
  height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

var x0 = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1);
var x1 = d3.scale.ordinal();

var y = d3.scale.linear()
  .range([height, 0]);
var colorRange = d3.scale.category20();
var color = d3.scale.ordinal()
  .range(colorRange.range());
var divTooltip = d3.select("body").append("div").attr("class", "toolTip");

var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x0)
  .orient("bottom");

var yAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(y)
  .orient("left")
  .ticks(10, "");

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
  .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

var options = d3.keys(obj[0]).filter(function(key) {
  if (key != "date_created" & key != "jobs_success") {
    return key
  }
}); // & key != "date_created"){return key} });

var line_option = d3.keys(obj[0]).filter(function(key) {
  if (key == "jobs_success" & key == "date_created") {
    return key
  }
});


obj.forEach(function(d) {
  d.valores = options.map(function(name) {
    return {
      name: name,
      value: +d[name]
    };
  });
});


x0.domain(obj.map(function(d) {
  return d.date_created;
}));
x1.domain(options).rangeRoundBands([0, x0.rangeBand()]);
y.domain([0, d3.max(obj, function(d) {
  return d.jobs_success
})]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
  .x(function(d) {
    return x0(d.date_created) + x0.rangeBand() / 2;
  })
  .y(function(d) {
    return y(d.jobs_success);
  });

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "x axis")
  .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  .call(xAxis);

svg.append("g")
  .attr("class", "y axis")
  .call(yAxis)
  .append("text")
  .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
  .attr("y", 6)
  .attr("dy", ".71em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text("Number of jobs");

var bar = svg.selectAll(".bar")
  .data(obj)
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "rect")
  .attr("transform", function(d) {
    return "translate(" + x0(d.date_created) + ",0)";
  });

bar.selectAll("rect")
  .data(function(d) {
    return d.valores;
  })
  .enter().append("rect")
  .attr("width", x1.rangeBand())
  .attr("x", function(d) {
    return x1(d.name);
  })
  .attr("y", function(d) {
    return y(d.value);
  })
  .attr("value", function(d) {
    return d.name;
  })
  .attr("height", function(d) {
    return height - y(d.value);
  })
  .style("fill", function(d) {
    return color(d.name);
  });

bar
  .on("mousemove", function(d) {
    divTooltip.style("left", d3.event.pageX + 10 + "px");
    divTooltip.style("top", d3.event.pageY - 25 + "px");
    divTooltip.style("display", "inline-block");
    var x = d3.event.pageX,
      y = d3.event.pageY
    var elements = document.querySelectorAll(':hover');
    l = elements.length
    l = l - 1
    elementData = elements[l].__data__
    divTooltip.html((d.date_created) + "<br>" + elementData.name + "<br>" + elementData.value);
  });
bar
  .on("mouseout", function(d) {
    divTooltip.style("display", "none");
  });


var legend = svg.selectAll(".legend")
  .data(options.slice())
  .enter().append("g")
  .attr("class", "legend")
  .attr("transform", function(d, i) {
    return "translate(0," + i * 20 + ")";
  });

legend.append("rect")
  .attr("x", width - 18)
  .attr("width", 18)
  .attr("height", 18)
  .style("fill", color);

legend.append("text")
  .attr("x", width - 24)
  .attr("y", 9)
  .attr("dy", ".35em")
  .style("text-anchor", "end")
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  });
svg.append("path")
  .datum(obj)
  .attr("class", "line")
  .attr("d", line)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "red")
  .style("stroke-width", 2);
```

```css
.axis line,
.axis path {
  fill: none;
  stroke: black;
  shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: thanks for detailed explanation I got lots of d3 concept cleared which will help me going forward.

Answer (score -1):

Ok a couple of things. Your line's `x` function should be relying on `x0` not `x1`:

```
var line = d3.svg.line()
    .x(function(d) { return x0(d.date_created); })
    .y(function(d) { return y(d.jobs_success); });
```

And your path needs to be called like this:

```
svg.append("path")
      .attr("class", "line")
      .attr("d", line(obj));
```

That should get you most of the way there - you might want to tweak the maximum y-value, and shift the x co-ordinate of the line by `x0.rangeBand()/2` as well to make it line up properly with the centre of the bars.

Comment: look like something changed but I am not able to make any sense out of it see the updated attachment

Comment: thanks for   your answer it works basically passing line(obj) works for me thanks

Comment: That looks like progress - you just need to set the style of your `path` so it has no fill. Set the style as `fill: none; stroke: #F00; stroke-width: 2` in CSS or as a `style` attribute and it will make a lot more sense